# Navigation Drawer Listener Not Working in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I am trying to implement navigation drawer inside the fragment, but I am facing problem when I am implementing the NavigationListener in FeedFragment.java, can you please help me to solve the problem and help me knowing the procedure implementing listener and toolbar inside the fragment activity. I have added all the code structure below which I have used to implement it.and even attached screenshot. Many a thanks in advance.

[here is the screenshot which I am implementing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW0nm.png)

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.sirajm.boom.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


</FrameLayout>
```

fragment_feed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

  <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_fragment" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello Blank Fragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sirajm.boom;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.sirajm.boom.Fragments.FeedFragment;
import com.example.sirajm.boom.Fragments.twoFragment;
import com.example.sirajm.boom.Fragments.threeFragment;
import com.example.sirajm.boom.Fragments.fourFragment;
import com.example.sirajm.boom.Fragments.fiveFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_panel,new FeedFragment()).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_store:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_panel,new twoFragment()).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_orders:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_panel,new threeFragment()).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_service:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_panel,new fourFragment()).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_profile:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_panel,new fiveFragment()).commit();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        BottomNavigationHelper.disableShiftMode(navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_panel,new FeedFragment()).commit();
    }

}
```

FeedFragment.java

```
  package com.example.sirajm.boom.Fragments;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.example.sirajm.boom.R;


   public class FeedFragment extends Fragment implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    View rootView;
    public FeedFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(), drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener((NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) getActivity());




        return rootView;


    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_event:

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ev1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_news:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ev2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_offers:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ev3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_problems:

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ev4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_talents:

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ev5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_shortmov:

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ev6", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_share:

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ev7", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_send:

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;

    }

}
```

Comment: You should explain what your actual problem is.

Comment: @jdv navigationdraweritem listener not supporting in fragment is there any alternative for that? to implement the navigation drawer in fragment? and even toolbar in fragment

Comment: Place clarifications and details in the body of the question please.

Comment: The `app_bar_main` `<include>` should not be inside the `<NavigationView>`. It should be above it.

Comment: @jdv in beginning I have explained

Comment: @Mike M I have followed same as template

Comment: OK, well, then I guess I'm not following your expected design. Anyway, you never set the `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` on the `NavigationView` in the `Fragment`. You have the `onNavigationItemSelected()` method there, but `FeedFragment` does not `implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`, and you never call `setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)` on the `NavigationView`.

Comment: Hi @Mike I added SetNavigationItemSelectedListener but too the same problem I am facing problem with override method

Comment: You'll have to [edit] your question with your current code, so we can see the new setup. Also, I just wanna point out again that I really don't think you want that `<include>` inside the `<NavigationView>`. Did you notice, in your screenshot, that the `Toolbar` is only inside the drawer? Don't you want it in the main content area? If you've got the listener setup correctly, it might just be that that's interfering with the clicks on the menu items.

Comment: @Mike I have edited the code kindly check

Comment: If the navigation drawer is only in `FeedFragment`, then its listener should be there, not in the `Activity`. You've already got the `onNavigationItemSelected()` method there. Just change the class declaration to `public class FeedFragment extends Fragment implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`, and set the listener like so: `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);`. I'm not really sure how the code you have now isn't crashing, since `MainActivity` doesn't implement the `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` interface.

Comment: Hi @Mike Thank you, Have updated code and event edited FeedFragment.xml and after adding On Navigation interface, app is crashing and there is no error on Android monitor.

Comment: Well, I can't be certain of the cause without the stack trace, but the `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(...)` call is a problem. That's what I expected to crash in your last revision. It should be `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);`, since the `Fragment` is the listener now, and `this` refers to the current instance of it. The `Activity` is not setup correctly to be an `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`, so the expression you have there now will throw a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @Mike then what will be the solution for it?

Comment: I mention it in my previous comment. Change that line to `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);`

Comment: @Mike Thank a lot :) its working

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make your base activity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener

Then add these those calls

```
 DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

So you don't need to implement it from fragment.
You just replace or add the fragments.